# Simple React form is not showing the default value (reactHooks)

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm following the official React docs to build a simple form which, however, doesn't work as intended.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("banana")

...

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
```

As far as I understood, it has to display "banana" as the initial value, whereas it shows "grapefruit". Why is it so?

Here's the link to the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

In the "Forms" section there's an example from where I took the code. It, however, uses class-based components while I use reactHooks. Might it be the problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It shows the first option because `value` isn't an attribute of `<select>`. If you want to select one, you need to add a `selected` attribute to one of the options.

For example:

```
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option selected={true} value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

This is generally written as

```
    const options = ["grapefruit", "lime", "coconut", "mango"];
    const selectedValue = "lime";
    <label>
      Pick your favorite flavor:
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        {options.map(o => (<option value={o} selected={o == selectedValue}>{o}</option>)}
      </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `banana` is not in `options`. If `option`'s  value is not present then it will by default pick the first one(Default behaviour). [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bohr-yk5po?file=/src/App.js:0-549)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("mango");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(() => {
      return e.target.value;
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
        <option value="lime">Lime</option>
        <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        <option value="mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```